# How to fetch monthly attendance report from attendance table through mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I need to show monthly attendance report for a particular student from MySQL table. I need result like below,

I have attendance table in my database which is shown in the image below:

[image]

I want to fetch data from my attendance table where **remarks '1' means 'present'** like below:
I need MySQL query to fetch the data like below

**Please anyone help me to write query**

My query is

```
SELECT YEAR(att_date) AS y, MONTH(att_date) AS m, COUNT(DISTINCT att_date) FROM attendance WHERE class_id=11 AND student_id=15 GROUP BY y, m
```

But didn't got the expected result as below

For **student-ID- 15**

```
CLASS   STUDENT_ID  YEAR    MONTH   TOTAL_CLASSES   TOTAL_PRESENT

11      15      2016    April         21             20
11      15      2016    May           25             25
11      15      2016    June          30             29
11      15      2016    July          18             18
11      15      2017    January       28             28
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e76fb/11**

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(att_date) AS `YEAR`, 
    MONTHNAME(att_date) AS `MONTH`, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT att_date) as TOTAL_CLASSES,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(remarks != '0' 
                      AND class_id=@class_id
                      AND student_id=14, 
                      att_date, NULL)) as TOTAL_PRESENT
FROM attendance CROSS JOIN (SELECT @class_id :=
                            (SELECT class_id FROM attendance WHERE student_id = 14 LIMIT 1)) param
GROUP BY `YEAR`, MONTH(att_date);
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5c64/1 not getting proper result as TOTAL_CLASSES needs to be counted as per school_id, branch_id, session_id and class_id

Comment: No the original problem is to solve a fixed category i.e for fixed school_id by passing a condition as school_id, branch_id, and session_id. In the original problem I just to filter out for a particular school_id , Please see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5c64/1

Comment: Sure, I've given a up vote to you. May I get the new answer

Comment: Now I need to give condition to fetch attendance record for a particular school  as school_id please see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5c64/1 I have edited the query and suggest whether it is correct way to fetch.

Comment: I made some update on your link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8be39/2. CHeck if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae54c95/1

```
  SELECT 
YEAR(att_date) AS y, 
MONTH(att_date) AS m, 
COUNT(distinct  att_date) as TOTAL_CLASSES,
count(distinct IF(remarks = '1' or remarks ='2' or remarks ='3', att_date, NULL)) as TOTAL_PRESENT FROM attendance WHERE class_id=11 AND student_id=15 GROUP BY y, m
```

Comment: I'm not trying to count classes on the same date but want to count classes for different month and show as total classes to respective month also count total present for a particular student for respective month

 
I need total classes means count total att_date group by month and year regardless of student_id and total preasent as total att_date where student_id=15 and classs_id-11 and remarks = '1' group by month and year

Comment: Gotcha, cant really see your error then. all i can think of is that your att date has a time stamp which is messing with your distinct. Even it's not there in your table image. Which column is showing wrong data?

Comment: Here's http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45ac1/1 of results, seems to match your desired ones from what i can tell.

Comment: Updated answer in relation to comments on remarks, very simliar to Dylans response. Should do the job

Comment: Hi, Please see here it is giving wrong result for student_id=14 sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e76fb/3 Here TOTAL_CLASSES should be 3 in march and 6 in April and TOTAL_PRESENT should be 1 in march and 1 in april for student_id=14 
     
Please make sure that here TOTAL_CLASSES means total classes taken in school for the month and TOTAL_PRESENT means out of TOTAL_CLASSES by a particular student_id